# Deleting object from array

Tags: objective-c, object, multidimensional-array

i'm working on app for iphone on objective-c
i have array with object references 
If i remove item with object reference from array should i release this object additionally or it will be removed from memory automatically?

Answer (score 2):

When removed from array object gets released once. So if your retain/release are paired correctly in other places you must not release your object in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the `NSArray` (um, it *is* an `NSArray`, isn't it? C arrays provide no ownership management) is the only thing that owns the object -- that is, if the object added was acquired `autorelease`-d or you explicitly called `release` after adding -- then it will be cleaned up automatically on removal. Any other ownership claims will still need to be `release`-d as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your talking about `NSMutableArray`

And it does the release 'automatically'. 
So do

```
[array add:  @"SAFEY-STRING" ];
```

and don't do

```
[array add:  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"LEAKY-STRING"] ];
```